# How do I extract specific emails from list in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a huge list of emails and I have tried to extract only the good emails. The problem is that the domains are many since they might have some custom domain, in addition to the standard gmail domains. I am trying to take out the corporate domains from the list. Here is an example of my code. When I run the below code, I get all the emails in the list.

```
data = ['test@statefarm.com','test@gmail.com', 'test@yahoo.com', 'test@edwardjones.com']

#I want to remove the domains with statefarm.com or edwardjones.com
for email in data:
    if "statefarm.com" not in email or "edwardjones.com" not in email:
    # I have even tried but it still hasn't worked. 
    #if "statefarm.com" or "edwardjones.com" not in email:
        print(email)
```

Comment: Replace: or -> and

Comment: seems to work just fine.. Thanks. Also, am I limited to the number of "and"s that I can use? Edit - No I am not limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @djukha says, replace `or` to `and`, so do:

```
data = ['test@statefarm.com','test@gmail.com', 'test@yahoo.com', 'test@edwardjones.com']
for email in data:
    if "statefarm.com" not in email and "edwardjones.com" not in email:
        print(email)
```

But for even better:

```
data = ['test@statefarm.com','test@gmail.com', 'test@yahoo.com', 'test@edwardjones.com']
print('\n'.join(filter(lambda x: any(i in x for i in {"statefarm.com","edwardjones.com"}),data)))
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is the second one better?

Comment: @Kamikaze_goldfish Happy yo help :-), the second is shorter (one-liner) and better, faster!!!